# ComboBox doesn't show after setState or forceUpdate

Tags: reactjs, axios

my problem is that I want to get info If I'm authorized from API using axios.get before rendering the page. I did something like that. Everything is working perfectly but my  with a role to choose doesn't show.

I'm new in react. "this.forceUpdate()" <- same problem

If I delete my authorization check, eliminate const{authorized} = this.state and {authorized ?(...) I see the combobox.

```
class RegisterComponent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.checkAuthorizationStatus();
        M.AutoInit();
    }

    checkAuthorizationStatus(){
        axios.get(API_URL+`/logged_in`)
            .then(response=>{
               if(response.data.authenticated === true && response.data.principal.authorities[0].authority===`ROLE_ADMIN`){
                   this.setState({authorized:true})
               }
               else{
                   return <Redirect to="/login" />
               }
            })
    }



    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            role : 'ROLE_ADMIN',
            hasCreationFailed: false,
            showSuccessMessage: false,
            authorized : false,
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState(
            {
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
            }
        )
    }

    submitClicked = () => {
        console.log({login: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
            roles: [{"role":this.state.role}]})
        axios.post(API_URL + '/admin/register', {
            login: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
            roles: [{"role":this.state.role}]
        })
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({
                        showSuccessMessage: true,
                        hasCreationFailed: false
                    }
                )
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({
                    showSuccessMessage: false,
                    hasCreationFailed: true
                })
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
```

```
    render() {
        const{authorized} = this.state
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                {authorized ?(
                <div className="row container">
                    <div className="col s10 offset-s1 l4 offset-l4">
                        <div className="purple-text accent-2"><h5>Create New Account</h5></div>

                        <div className="input-field">
                            <select value={this.state.role} onChange={this.handleChange} name="role">
                                <option value='ROLE_ADMIN'>Administrator</option>
                                <option value='ROLE_TABLE'>Klient</option>
                                <option value='ROLE_WORKER'>Pracownik</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div className="input-field">
                            <input className="validate" type="text" id="username" name="username"
                                   value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value={this.state.password}
                                   onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        </div>


                        <button className="btn blue col l12 waves-effect waves-light"
                                onClick={this.submitClicked}>Zarejestruj użytkownika
                        </button>
                        {this.state.showSuccessMessage &&
                        <div className="green-text">Rejestracja zakończona powodzeniem</div>}
                        {this.state.hasCreationFailed && <div className="red-text">Rejestracja nie powiodła się</div>}
                    </div>
                </div>

            ):(<></>)}

                    </React.Fragment>

)}

}
export default RegisterComponent
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: I did mistake there "List role" doesn't show. It means <select></select> in render.

Comment: I have made this minimal [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nzk3rq). Check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `role` property of `state` in your `handleChange` since your `<select>` uses `value` from `this.state.role`

```
handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState(
            {
                role: event.target.value // update 'role' property
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: Still the same problem, I don't even see this list on page :(